# Image and overlay don't respect max-height and max-width, absolute div doesn't cover image

Tags: html, css, max, width, overlay

I have a vertical video in an `<a>` parent, as well as a div under it which is an overlay. I want to set max width and height parameters for the parent in terms of vh, but either the video doesn't follow them, or the overlay doesn't. The overlay is an absolute element, but they should both be inheriting the dimensions. Some code variations gave me the overlay that has a constant width (of the original video), or a constant height, and in this variation the video isn't covered by the overlay and only gets smaller after a certain point of it is already covered by the window (so it doesn't minimize according to max-height).

I'm tired of redoing this combination for hours trying to get the right result, does anyone know how I can achieve this with relatively simple styling?

I didn't want to include my real video, but it's a 424x754 mp4 file.

```css
.media-container {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 85vh;
  max-width: 95vh;
}

.media-container>video {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: .6;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<a class="media-container" href="">
  <video src="https://assets.mixkit.co/videos/preview/mixkit-waves-in-the-water-1164-large.mp4"></video>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</a>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

### **EDIT:**

Here's a css version that works closer to what I want, but it's still wrong because the video doesn't minimize when you decrease the window's width.

```css
.media-container {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 85vh;
  max-width: 95vh;
}

.media-container>video {
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 95vh;
  max-height: 85vh;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  right:0;left:0;top:0;bottom:0;
  opacity: .6;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<a class="media-container" href="">
  <video src="https://assets.mixkit.co/videos/preview/mixkit-waves-in-the-water-1164-large.mp4"></video>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</a>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: `.media-container-vertical>video` this isn't selecting anything, Also what is the end result here ?

Comment: Fixed, that was a typo from renaming my local classes, which I think would reduce readability

Comment: @ZohirSalak the snippets show an accurate result now

Comment: If you want the overlay to fill up the screen why not `100vh` ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak I don't want the overlay to fill the screen.. I want it to fill the video.

Comment: Oh in that case, something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/pews8hqk/) should do it

Comment: @ZohirSalak That's pretty close, actually! However I want to have a max-height of 85vh, and if I add that to media-container it just has the same behavior as my first example, I don't know why.

Comment: Why don't you add it to them both, since the containers height is defined by the video

Comment: @ZohirSalak That's the thing, even when I add max-width and max-height to both, the video doesn't minimize on reduced window width. It really feels like an impossible problem.

I have a working version of a correctly covered video overlay, but it doesn't respect the max-width limit.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're after nor what the problem is, max-height on the video should answer your question

Comment: @ZohirSalak I updated my post, the problem is I need BOTH max-height and max-width, but the result is that either only one of them works, or if they both work then the overlay doesn't.

Comment: It doesn't respect the width because you're using `vh` for the width you should use `vw`

Comment: @ZohirSalak WOW!!! Thank you so much! I don't know how I missed it but that definitely helped solve it, as well as putting the limits on both elements like you said. I appreciate it man.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are after, but adding an explicit setting of `width` and `height` (in `vh`) to the anchor tag (`.media-container`) seems to make things better:

```css
.media-container {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 85vh;
  max-width: 95vh;
  
  /* added these two lines */
  width: 95vh;
  height: 85vh;
}

.media-container-vertical>video {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: .6;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<a class="media-container" href="">
  <video src="https://assets.mixkit.co/videos/preview/mixkit-waves-in-the-water-1164-large.mp4"></video>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work. I edited your snippet to change the overlay color to red so you can see. The issue is that I want the width to still be less than 95vh when the window is in landscape , and the max-width is only set to 95vh so it would minimize it on mobile devices.